# Strip whitespace in generated HTML using pure Python code

Tags: python, html, whitespace, strip, jinja2

I am using Jinja2 to generate HTML files which are typically very huge in size. I noticed that the generated HTML had a lot of whitespace. Is there a pure-Python tool that I can use to minimize this HTML? When I say "minimize", I mean remove unnecessary whitespace from the HTML (much like Google does -- look at the source for google.com, for instance)

I don't want to rely on libraries/external-executables such as tidy for this.

For further clarification, there is virtually no JavaScript code. Only HTML content.

Comment: Do you *just* want to remove unnecessary whitespace or are you looking for something more? Your title suggests whitespace only, but from your question you seem to be looking for a more complete tool.

Comment: @Mark: Just removing whitespace alone should be sufficient, I believe. (Is there anything more than that at all?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you just want to get rid of excess whitespace, you can use:

```
>>> import re
>>> html_string = re.sub(r'\s\s+', ' ', html_string)
```

or:

```
>>> html_string = ' '.join(html_string.split())
```

If you want to do something more complicated than just stripping excess whitespace, you'll need to use more powerful tools (or more complex regexps).

Comment: This way you will also strip spaces between words in text like in paragraphs and tag attributes and make HTML invalid

Comment: It is also breaking the contents of <pre> elements.

Answer (score 9):

You might also investigate [Jinja's built-in whitespace control](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/templates#whitespace-control), which might alleviate some of the need for manually removing whitespace after your templates have been rendered.

Quoting [the docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/templates#whitespace-control):

> But you can also strip whitespace in templates by hand. If you put an minus sign (-) to the start or end of an block (for example a for tag), a comment or variable expression you can remove the whitespaces after or before that block:

```
{% for item in seq -%}
    {{ item }}
{%- endfor %}
```

> This will yield all elements without whitespace between them. If seq was a list of numbers from 1 to 9 the output would be 123456789.

Comment: But this only handles whitespace between blocks -- not within blocks, or non-block content (such has hand-written paragraphs)

Answer (score 4):

I found [python slimmer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimmer/) library, perfect for what you need to do.

```
from slimmer import html_slimmer # or xhtml_slimmer, css_slimmer
html = html_slimmer(html)
```